# Page hit count not visible on pages

Tags: 7, nodes

I installed and configured statistics module and I am successful of obtaining reports. However, I wanted to view the page hit count on each page, which I am not getting. What I did:
1. Installed and configured statistics module
2.Enabled Access Log --> discard access logs older than 3 days
3. Checked count content views
4. Administer statistics and view content access statistics permission only for the administrator
5.view content hits permission for all users (authenticated/administrator/anonymous).
After all these, when I open a node or a page, I am not able to view anything related to reads or hits or page views. 
Please suggest me, what should I do?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to enable Count content views in the same configuration page and don't need to enable access log.

Comment: I did but no use... Is there anything I must do in the template files? Thank you in advance...